# Djangoで JavaScript を扱いたいのですが、なかなかエラーが消えません。

Tags: python, javascript, python3, django

https://code.i-harness.com/ja/q/48f14

上記のサイトを参考にして、js.pyを追加し、htmlファイルに以下のように記述しましたが、
`(% load js %}` のところでエラーが出てしまいます。

```
{% load js %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    var someVar = {{ some_var | js }};
</script>
```

**結果**

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: 'js' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_static
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
static
staticfiles
tz
```

settings.pyファイルを変更したりいろいろ試しましたが、解決せず、困っております。

**実行環境**

Python 3.4.3
Django 2.0